# How to get summery of multiple realm files from realm-object-server

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

In my realm mobile platform, One user can use 10 realm files and each file having no of records. like one file has 2, another 3, etc.. How I can get all records to count from all realm files which are present in my server.

I tried but it's creating a local copy of each realm file which is not a good approach is there any API or something else by which I can get a summary of all realm files.

Comment: You wrote, that you tried something. Can you provide that code and point out to where you have the issues.

Comment: My point is I can access one realm file and get all the records which it has but if I want a summary of all realm files how can I? That's the question.